# Reading a text file

Tags: c++

Here is what I have so far. The problem am having now is reading and inserting the strings of words I have in my text file named "word.txt" into the trie tree. I used the "void init()"function to test that the tree functions and it does but using the text file, thats where I don't know how to

any idea please

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>



class TrieNode {
public:
    // Initialize your data structure here.
    TrieNode() {
        value = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<26;i++){
            children[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    int value;
    TrieNode* children[26];
};

class Trie {

private:
    TrieNode*root;
    int count;


public:
    Trie() {
        root = new TrieNode();
        count = 0;
    }

    // Inserts a word into the trie.
    void insert(string s) {
        TrieNode *p = root;
        long int len = s.size();
        for (int i=0;i<len;i++){
            int index = s[i] - 'a';
            if (! p->children[index]){
                p->children[index] = new TrieNode();
            }
            p = p->children[index];
        }
        count++;
        p->value = count;
    }

    // Returns if the word is in the trie.
    // -1 if not in trie and not prefix of anything in trie
    // 0 if not in trie but is a prefix of something in trie
    // 1 if in trie
    int search(string key) {
        TrieNode *p = root;
        long int lenght = key.size();
        for (int i=0;i<lenght;i++){
            int index = key[i] - 'a';
            if (p->children[index]){
                p = p->children[index];
            }
            else{
                return -1;
            }
        }
        if (p->value!=0){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }

    }

};


//Game class using a tree
class GhostGame{
private:
    string row;
    ifstream fin;
    string wordSoFar = "";
    string Player1,Player2;
    Trie Tree;
public:
    void ReadFile(){
       ifstream fin("word.txt");

        while (!fin.eof()) { // read file till the end
            fin>>row;
            getline(fin,row);
            cout << row << endl;
            Tree.insert(row);
        }
        //fin.close();
    }
    void init(){
        Tree.insert("ab");
        Tree.insert("acd");
    }


    //start menu
    void StartGame(){
        init();
        cout<<"========================="<<endl;
        cout<<"Welcome to Ghost Game"<<endl;
        cout<<"========================="<<endl;

        //ReadFile();
        while(Tree.search(wordSoFar)!=1){
            cout<< "Player 1 Insert a letter => ";
            cin>> Player1;
            cout<<setw(60)<<"now =  ["<< wordSoFar <<"]"<<endl;
            wordSoFar +=Player1;
            if(Tree.search(wordSoFar)==1){
                cout<< "Player 2 Wins "<<endl;
                break;
            }

            cout<< "Player 2 Insert a letter => ";
            cin>>Player2;
            cout<<setw(60)<<"now =  ["<< wordSoFar<<"]"<<endl;
            wordSoFar += Player2;
            if(Tree.search(wordSoFar)==1){
                cout<< "Player 1 Wins "<<endl;
                break;
            }

        }
    }};



// main driver
int main()
{

    GhostGame G1;
    G1.StartGame();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ....... What have you tried so far? Where have you searched before? This site is not for doing the thought work for you......

Comment: You are asking people to do your job, not to help you.
You need to say what you tried not just "DO THIS FOR ME"

Comment: There is a type of tree whose name I have forgotten that is built for this kind of searching.

Comment: Now I remember! [Trie! It's called a trie!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Open file
- using fgets or get line function read the file into temporary string
- check first character... Make sure to use tolower, before comparing

  ```
  void findString(char *filename, char ch)
  {
    char temp[100];
    FILE *infile = fopen(filename, "rw");
    while(infile != NULL)
    {
      fgets(temp,100,infile);

      if(tolower(temp[0]) == ch)
         cout << temp;
    }
    fclose(infile);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions for such task, they are in header file `<regex>`. Some good tutorials on regex can be found in book Professional C++ (Wrox) for example.

For file reading use ifstream class from `<fstream>`.